# Why is Operations Research considered mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, operations-research

Today I learned that there exists a field called Operations Research that is supposed to be a field of mathematics according to sources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research).

Could someone explain to me, what is Operations Research and in what ways is it a field of mathematics?

Comment: Maybe "applied" mathematics.

Comment: In the same sense that game theory, mathematical physics and statistics are part of mathematics.

Comment: Mathematical problems in real-life situations: https://www.informs.org/

Comment: If it was good enough for Von Neumann, it's mathematics.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim I guess I'm looking for something that could give me a similar feeling of familiarity like with the fields you mention. I can tell that it's some kind of applied field that uses some kind of mathematics. But what is the motivation, what is the purpose of that field? I don't know

Comment: I know it's a type of question that anyone can ask, but I don't expect answers that anyone can tell me, but more on the focus of the subject

Comment: Have a look at Operations Research by Taha if you want something fairly mathematical. Have a look at Management Science by Taylor et al if you want something simpler and more business focussed.

Comment: @Jakobian I know it is a vague answer, but that seems only reasonable for a vague question. OR is basically the study of optimization of systems, in a very broad sense. In practise, it is often the study of optimization of mathematical models modelling some real world system, such as railroads, the economy, design processes, AI etc.
What characterises a field of mathematics? I would say a common language, the axiomatic-deductive method, and back-and-forth influence with other fields. All of these are present in the case of OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations research (OR) is an interdisciplinary, applied$^{[1]}$ field that is strongly focused in mathematical optimization, and the construction deployment of mathematical models$^{[2]}$ - with the dominating subjects in the field being Linear and Nonlinear optimization (which are also known as Linear Programming and Nonlinear Programming in the field of OR, as there exists *a lot* of connections with Computer Science).

The origin of Operations Research is quite debated, as some claim that [Charles Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) is the original creator of OR for his work in optimizing the mailing system in England in the 1800's. Nevertheless, every starting story that you will find usually says it started out with an optimization problem that needed to be solved, and by solving that problem it led to the development of some-sort of new subject, or method, that went on to define how we handle optimization problems of the present (George Dantzig is a good example of this, as his invention of [the Simplex method](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/87252.88081) in 1947 is still one of the best linear optimization algorithms of the present)

Here is a (non-exhaustive) list of some subjects that are a part of OR:

- [Network Optimization](https://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-08.pdf)
- [Linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), [Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), and [Nonlinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming) Programming
- [Constraint Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming)
- [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)
- [Convex Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization)

The mentioned subjects are quite dense by themselves, but someone who is into OR is expected to know some of each subject mentioned above near fluently. In addition, since it is an applied field, a majority of those who are into OR are working to solve real-world optimization problems - with the biggest employers of OR being the military (US Air Force) and large companies (Amazon, Walmart, etc). However, the field does give itself wiggle-room for those who like to develop new algorithmic methods (heuristics and metaheuristics) for unique optimization problems. [Here is a thread](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/7506/10807) on some of the recent developments in the field.

Thus, Operations Research can be said to be a part of mathematics as it is *foundationally* rooted in using the same axioms and methods like any other applied mathematical field. The sole difference between this field and others is that it makes mathematical optimization its sole focus and motive.

---

**Tangential Remarks**

$[ 1 ]$ [Here is a thread](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1106/10807) that explains how OR is begin used to solve and assist with other pure math subjects

$[2]$ It cannot be stressed enough how mathematical models are the backbone of OR. While a lot of other fields pre-dating OR structured and used variations of mathematical models to solve their own field-related problems, OR took it several leagues further by unifying the language of the model across multiple fields, and tries to shown that a wide variety of problems of almost all backgrounds are able to be abstracted into models and solved. Half of the beauty from this field is being shocked, and mystified, when someone develops an extremely beautiful model to a complex problem.